# Use Action<T1,T2> when register Method in Messenger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-foundation

I'm using mvvm pattern, and have the next situation.
For example exists a method:

```
    void LockPressed(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       // Code
    }
```

And here I register it:

```
    App.Messenger.Register("LockPressed", (Action<KeyEventArgs>)LockPressed);
```

Thath works fine. But If I need to modify method, for it to take two parameters:

```
    void LockPressed(KeyEventArgs e, string name)
    {
       //Code
    }
```

Logicaly resgister operation should look like:

```
    App.Messenger.Register("LockPressed", (Action<KeyEventArgs,string>)LockPressed);
```

But no success. I got an error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Action' to 'System.Action'

Any ideas how can I workaround it?

Comment: If you can, that'll be more easy to make custom `EventArgs` those, will aggregate `KeyEventArgs` and `Name`

Comment: @Jehof MVVM Foundation

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
App.Messenger.Register("LockPressed", (KeyEventArgs eventArgs)=>LockPressed(eventArgs, "name"));
```

or more complex

```
App.Messenger.Register("LockPressed", (KeyEventArgs eventArgs)=>
  {
    string name = GetName();
    LockPressed(eventArgs, name);
  });
```

or

```
Action<KeyEventArgs> lockPressedAction = (eventargs) => LockPressed(eventargs,"g");
App.Messenger.Register("LockPressed", lockPressedAction);
```

Comment: Delegate 'Action' does not take 1 arguments

Comment: @MCv what if you define it explicitly like `Action<KeyEventArgs> lockPressedAction = (eventargs) => LockPressed(eventargs,"g");` and then call `App.Messenger.Register("LockPressed", lockPressedAction);`

Comment: you don't need the paranthesis around eventargs. `Register("LockPressed", eventArgs => LockPressed(eventArgs, "name"));` should work fine. (if there are more than one argument they are required though)